# How does Whois/Domain privacy work?

Tags: dns, domain, privacy

How exactly, and moreover, why does Domain privacy work? Some sources state that you need to buy it from your hosting/domain provider, but others state that it comes by default on some domains.

And if you get it with some domains anyway, who decides which domains get it by default?

But other sources state that it's not even supported ([Name.com](https://name.com/support/articles/205188698-TLDs-that-do-not-support-Whois-Privacy) and [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy) seem to contradict each other on .eu domains)

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the links to the conflicting resources? As a "domain" is not a limited pool of names, there's no authority that determines that the ownership info of a given domainname `example.com` should automatically be hidden. For different top-level domains regulations exist, for example info on all .us domains must be made public, whereas the only publicly available information for .eu domains by default is the registrants email address; if the registrant is a person. This is determined by applicable data privacy laws.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of how whois privacy works:

Whois used to provide administrative contact details about the person registering the domain. In this way, the provider doesn't need to handle issues with the domain, but directs any problems to the admin contact. Unfortunately this was abused by stalkers, etc. And so the net result is some dns providers will mask the whois contact details with their own admin contact. Since the downside to the provider is having to deal with any inquirers, not everyone will do this.

DNS privacy like DoH and dnscurve on the other hand, work by limiting visibility by intermediate providers into dns queries and replies by encrypting the communication and/or having verified dns replies. Unfortunately, there's only just a few number of providers for dns privacy, and ultimately the dns provider can match the queried dns names to the dns client ip addresses.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).